# Is there a name for a person who has 2-3 citizenships?

Tags: word-request

Is there a name for a person who has 2 or 3 citizenships?

It should be an *adjective* or *noun* that can describe this person.

By intuition, I guess that if there is,  for the one who has 2 citizenships the name should start with the prefix "bi-…", while for the one who has more than 2 citizenships the name should start with "multi-…"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it happens, I have citizenship in two different countries. In other words, I have **dual citizenship**. That makes me a **dual citizen**.

According to Merriam-Webster, even if I were a citizen of three or more countries, I would still have **dual** citizenship, though Wikipedia thinks I would have **multiple** citizenship.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dual%20citizenship

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_citizenship

Comment: Thank you for your answer ^1+) So it can be used also as an adjective? Would it be "Are you a dual citizen?" or "Are you a multiple citizen?" Just pay attention that I asked for name of a person who holds 2 or more citizenships, that says it should be a noun or an adjective for a person. ("dual citizenship" doesn't describe the person(

Comment: Yes, a person can be a dual citizen or a multiple citizen -- which I actually did mention in the answer ;)